# How could I automate business usecases in Salesforce.com?

Tags: .net, salesforce, qtp

How could I automate business usecases in Salesforce.com?

1. Can I use QTP as the automation tool?
2. Is there any open source framework exist?
3. Is there any licensed framework exist?
4. Is there any tool kit published by Salesforce.com?

Please share your observation.

Comment: "Yes" to question #1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Workflow and Approvals](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wf.htm&language=en_US)?  [Mulesoft](https://www.mulesoft.com/integration-solutions/saas/salesforce) is also popular.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of automation tools that can do the job. UiPath, Selenium, Automation Anywhere, Ranorex, QTP, etc.

I have used [UiPath](http://www.uipath.com) in order to accomplish any kind automation (web, desktop, java, citrix, wpf, flash). Here's a [tutorial on automating salesforce web](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/web-automation-data-entry-csv-salesforce). It has an SDK so can be used from C# code. However the workflow designer is a very powerful tool when it comes to UI automation so I would start with it. It lets you create visual automation (see the picture). More details [here](http://www.uipath.com/web-automation).

[image]

Note: I work at UiPath. You should also try other visual automation tools like Automation Anywhere, WinAutomation, Jacada, use them side by side and choose the one that suits better your needs.